# PHP - empty array

Tags: php, arrays, variables

`(array)$someemptyvariablethatisnotarray` returns `array([0] =>)` instead of `array()`

How can I make it so I get a empty array that is not iterated when I'm using it inside foreach() ?

Comment: When you use `var_dump()` instead of `print_r()` it shows you also the type of the value in the array!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The feature which you are using, is called "[casting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)". This means a variable is forced to become a given type, in your example an array. How the var is converted is not always obvious in PHP!

In your example $someemptyvariablethatisnotarray becomes an array with one entry with a NULL value.

The [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) says:

> The behaviour of an automatic
>   conversion to array is currently
>   undefined.

To solve your code I would recommend something like this:

```
if (!is_array($someemptyvariablethatisnotarray) {
    $someemptyvariablethatisnotarray = array();
}
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting

Comment: If you casted NULL as an array, it would become a blank array, if you cast a scalar value (even an empty string, because that's not NULL) it becomes an array with that value, not a NULL value.

Answer (score 25):

```
$var = array();
```

will empty an array. Is this what you're after?

Answer (score 4):

```
if(!$variable){
        return array();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$somevar = empty($somevar) ? array() : (array)$somevar;
```

Maybe? Though I'm not sure I get the cast, or the purpose. Care to ellaborate a bit more (maybe an example of what you're trying to accomplish?)

Comment: I'm using it like `foreach((array)$something as $k)...`. Sometimes $something may be "false" and not a array, so I don't want foreach  to iterate it

Comment: @Alexandra: I know PHP's flexible, but if you're finding your variables switching datatypes on you, there should be a check somewhere else to catch that (don't rely on a cast in other words). I'm going to jump the gun and assume it's database related, and a fetch row which could potentially return a FALSE which would inhibit you iterating over the elements, correct?

Comment: yes :) I hate making checks for every small thing, but I guess I have no choice here..

Comment: @Alexandra: I might advise `while (($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) !== false){ ... }`. That's still a "check". ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Try `unset($someemptyvariablethatisnotarray[0])` :)

Answer (score 3):

how are you?

I believe this is what you're after:

```
$something = false;
foreach((array)(empty($something) ? null : $something) as $k){
    echo 'never enters here';
}
```

You don't get an empty array, because when you set "(array)false", **it means you'll have a single element, and that element will have the "FALSE" value assigned to it.**

Same happens with an empty string *(not a null one!)* (array)$emptystring will return an array which contains a single element, which is an empty string!

Similar to doing:

```
array('');
```

Hope it helps.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

When you cast a non-array as an array, it creates an array with that variable as the only value.

If you want an empty array, you need to return `array()`.

Answer (score 0):

just use `count()`, for example: `if(count($array) == 0 ){  // empty array }`